# How do we determine if an operator over real functions is normal?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, legendre-polynomials

We have the operator $T(f) = (pf')'$, where $p(x) = x^2 - 1$. The inner product is $\displaystyle (f,g) = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x) dx$. How do we infer whether eigenfunctions corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating twice by parts,
$$(T(f),g)=-(pf',g')=-(f',pg')=(f,T(g))$$
hence $T$ is self-adjoint.